# How to get my Android to give audio reminders of Google Calendar appointments?

Tags: android, calendar, google-apps, reminders

I would like to follow up on [nibarius’s recent question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2502/), because I have the same issue. Except on my Android I can find no Calendar settings within Settings. Nor is there anything about Calendar under Notifications anywhere. Ditto when I open the calendar itself: no setting that pertains to notifications. I'm using Android 4.1.2.

The frustrating thing is I remember a time when this phone would give me audio notifications from my Google Calendar.

Comment: Do you need something different than what [nibarius asked for](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2502/60)? (if yes, you should [edit] your question and describe what you need) -- Or do you have exactly the same requirements, and it just happens that the solution from [Michael Kohne’s answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2507/60) does not work for you? (if yes, your question should be closed as duplicate; you could either wait for alternative solutions added to nibarius’s question, or ask a support question on why the solution does not work, e.g., on [android.se])

Answer (score 2):

If your calendar app doesn't give that options (which makes me wonder, as I never encoutered a device that had *no* reminder options), you might wish to take a look at some available [Calendar-Alarm-Fixes](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_alarmfixes).

In the past, I had used [Calendar Event Reminder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.foobarsoft.calendareventreminder), which lets you chose the calendars it should care for, and even gives more options to the reminders: Not only it let's you chose the sound, but you can also define how long it should nag you and in what intervals (so you never miss an alert because you were "shortly separated" from your device). Additionally, you can set up "snoozes" to delay the alarm for a given time. But other than you request, the app doesn't come for free.

The linked list holds some alternatives, some of them come for free – but I cannot say how well those work, as I didn't use them. I've meanwhile switched to [Business Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netgenius.bizcal) as calendar replacement, which in the Pro version also ships with an own reminder system. Again, that's not free. But that wasn't one of your requirements either, so both seem to be valid solutions for you.

Comment: I can't access your first link. It requires some kind of authentication

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Link fixed now.